# Why does this question belong on superuser?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://superuser.com/questions/13830

I am not whining, just wondering

Answer (score 6):

Bill the Lizard moved it with his witchcraft, but I suspect it was because it isn't really about programming.  It's asking for a plugin for his blog; not how to design a plugin, not how to work with the API of a plugin, not how to import a plugin into his custom blog software.

Comment: But how is that about computers?

Comment: The Internet runs on computers, last time I checked.

Comment: On servers actually... does that make it a question for serverfault?

Comment: Because SU is the general-purpose computer site.  If it belongs anywhere, it's there.  Migrate it over to them, and if they don't want it, TheTXI can practice his own witchcraft and send it to a watery grave.

Comment: No, because it's not a question about maintaining servers. It's on superuser because it's not programming related, not server related and not SO related, but it's still about computers. It's a guy looking for a plugin, for something other than an IDE or something else at least slightly related to programming.

Comment: Somebody take the razor away from Juan.  Enough splitting hairs, already.

Comment: @Welbog and Juan: Duh! Don't you guys know the internet runs on **tubes**!

Comment: @gnovice: I thought it was a dumptruck!

Comment: @Welbog: The dumptruck is just the *interface*. It empties everything into the tubes.

Comment: @gnovice: You have thoroughly blown my mind.

Comment: @gnovice: So should this question have been migrated to the dumptruck or the tubes?!

Comment: @Pesto: I'd say it's dumptruck-related, since it's basically asking for a way to ferry garbage from one tube input to another. ;)

Comment: Ahem. Its a _series_ of tubes but it'll take Joe the Plumber to unclog it from all the crap thats been flushed down it lately.

Answer (score 5):

It's a judgement call, and anytime it's close it's going to end up on the more general site because it only takes 5 users who favor that site to push it there.

That said, in this case I suspect it's because it's not talking about writing or changing any new code, but just looking to setup or configure something that's already written.

Comment: It's not my question btw

Comment: Noted, re-worded.

Answer (score 2):

Curious; I probably wouldn't have migrated that, but it is sometimes a tricky call. You'd be surprised how odd things get; I had a moderator flag earlier asking (quite correctly) for a moderator to save a SO post about using **linux on a laptop** from going to SF, when it is clearly SU material (it was 1 vote away from SF).

Comment: But it was Linux! Which is a **Server** OS!!

Comment: @Shog9 - I am not sure if I should laugh or cry. Either would result in me slitting my wrists :|